# PyCharm: Why does signature not match in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Consider the following code example:

```py
class BaseExtractor(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def extract(self, interval, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError

class ChildExtractor(BaseExtractor):

    def extract(self, interval, variants, anchor, fixed_len=True, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Why does PyCharm tell me that `ChildExtractor.extract()` does not match `BaseExtractor.extract()`?

I start to think that I'm just having some very stupid mistake...

EDIT:

```py
class ChildExtractor(BaseExtractor):

    def extract(self, interval, variants, anchor, *args, fixed_len=True, **kwargs):
        pass
```

This results in the same error.

Comment: Presumably because the Base extract() takes any number of positional arguments but there is no *args in the Child extract().

Comment: Try adding *args into the ChildExtractor's extract method.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, this still gives the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following usage of `BaseExtractor`:

```py
def extractor_usage(extractor: BaseExtractor):
    extractor.extract(interval=10)
```

It correctly uses `BaseExtractor` interface but passing `ChildExtractor` to this method leads to `TypeError`.

The issue could be fixed by making `variants` and `anchor` optional, e.g.:

```py
class ChildExtractor(BaseExtractor):

    def extract(self, interval, variants=None, anchor=None, *args, fixed_len=True, **kwargs):
        pass

extractor_usage(ChildExtractor())  # No TypeError here
```

Comment: In other words, the subclass method is not allowed to have additional required arguments (any additional arguments must be optional or have a default value).